# Axis2Fault detailed description

Tags: java, soap, error-handling, apache-axis, soap-client

I have created a java client to make web service call to a remote axis2 service deployed. I generated the client stubs with the WSDL file downloaded from the remote server's  "/?wsdl" endpoint and tested a sample call for one of the exposed operations. It failed with the AxisFault error:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method "sample operation"
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
```

The above error appears quite generic and doesn't help much in knowing the actual reason. Please suggest a way of getting more detailed error reason. Is there any attribute of AxisFault entity that is populated with a detailed error description which I can log or there is some other way?